# SSRS- the existing report shows result based on the person running the report, how to remove this functionality?

Tags: ssrs-2008

There is one existing SSRS report (which was created by another person in the team) which shows the result data only for the person who is running the report.
I want to remove this functionality and show the result set irrespective of the person running the report and show all the data for all the people.
Could anyone please suggest how to remove this functionality?
I am using Visual Studio 2008.
I read that User.UserID might help but I don't see that being added in the existing old report.
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality works  when you use the user.user id built in functions.
You could go ahead and check if any of the parameters defined in the report is using the user.user id function.
Especially the default value part of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I checked for all the parameters and none of them use user.user id built in function. Few parameters use static text as default value and few of them get values from a query- using a dataset. Is there anything else I should be checking? It may be possible that this report is showing the data irrespective of the person running it and I may need to verify that, is there anyway to check that?

Comment: I think you should check the filter tab available in all the datasets. Since you found no parameters having the user.user id function this would be the second best guess. If you do not find any filters in the datasets then the problem must be different.

Comment: I checked the filter tabs of all the datasets and couldn't find anything. Is it possible that this functionality is written in stored procedure we are using? I am trying to see what other ways are there to restrict data depending on the user running it.

Comment: If there isn't a filter or a parameter using the user! user id function then it's definitely not possible to do it in any other way.
You could check the datasets to see if there is any restrictions based on roles or users hardcoded in the queries or SP's

Comment: My pleasure...hopefully it helped you solve your problem.
Would be helpful if u could upvote the answer.

Comment: I realized that I was looking into copy of the rdl file which was changed little bit whereas the main rdl file was saved somewhere else and found out that it had that parameter where User.UserID built in function was used. So, I performed the following tasks: 1-removed that parameter and the dataset associated to this parameter 2-checked that the Tablix also had the same dataset used in the FilterExpression in the Tablix Properties, removed that too from Filters tab. Now, the report works absolutely fine. Thank you so much for your great help! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was looking into copy of the rdl file which was changed little bit whereas the main rdl file was saved somewhere else and found out that it had that parameter where User.UserID built in function was used.
So, I performed the following tasks:
1-removed that parameter and the dataset associated to this parameter 
2-checked that the Tablix also had the same dataset used in the FilterExpression in the Tablix Properties, removed that too from Filters tab.
Now, the report works absolutely fine.
Thank you so much for your great help! Really appreciate it :)